# NPM and Yarn is having issues with fsevents

Tags: npm, package, yarnpkg

I tried to spin up my project today and when I wanted to start it, I got an error saying that something was wrong with fsevents package.

After that I tried to reinstall all the packages again with yarn and I got the same, the install stops and fails when it comes to the fsevents package. Same thing happens with npm.

I have the latest node version if that counts.

Here is the errors I get when trying to install with npm:

[image: errors]

Can I get some help with this please? Tried to google but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: could be many issues from using an older version of npm or nodejs or a conflict in your node_modules directory.  Have you tried to install the dependency by itself, npm install fsevents?

Comment: I just did yes, it installs it (with an error though) then it complains about `node-pre-gyp` and gives me almost the same error with a 403 code

Comment: Did you see this thread? Not sure what versions you're running of node and npm but you may try upgrading grpc see  https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9311